# MUI v5 stylesheets custom mount point

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, shadow-dom

I'm trying to use Shadow Dom inside of chrome extension.
If I wrap my app in Shadow Dom it doesn't have mui styles (they are added to `head` - which is not available inside of Shadow Dom).

I want to somehow point where mui css styles should be mounted.

All information I can find online is from previous version and doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

MUI use `@emotion` library for writing CSS styles with JavaScript. MUI inject all `styles` in `head` so you have to inject those styles in targeted element in Shadow Dom instead of `head`.

Install `@emotion/cache` and `@emotion/react` for injecting MUI styles into target element.

Code example:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App.jsx';
import createCache from '@emotion/cache';
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';

function AppContainer() {
    let cashCache = createCache({
        key: 'shadow-dom-css',
        prepend: true,
        container: document
            .getElementById('shadow-dom-root')
            .shadowRoot.querySelector('#emotion-styled-container'),
        speedy: false,
    });
    
    return (
        <CacheProvider value={cashCache}>
            <App />
        </CacheProvider>
    );
}

export default AppContainer;
```

For more info: https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/shadow-dom/

Comment: How to do it for MUI4? Any ideas?